# will frame() in Image on SwiftUI has different size for each devices?

Tags: image, frame, swiftui

I have a code for View with Image in swiftUI, I wonder if the frame() function will produces different size for each devices(like iPhone 8, Xs, Xs+, etc)

```
struct CircleImage : View {
    var body: some View {
        Image("jorge")
            .resizable()
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
            .clipShape(Circle())
            .overlay(
                Circle().stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 4))
            .shadow(radius: 10)

    }
}
```

I have Xcode 11 with beta of course, but I don't have catalina since I have to do my work with Mojave and Catalina doesn't support it. So I can't find any clues with SwiftUI Preview.

I also tried to see above code with multiple simulators(with 8 and Xs+) and I saw that images seems have same size but I'm not sure for it.

And If the sizes are same, what is the standard size of screen? and if not, how can I find each screen's standards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but I'll do my best to answer. When you specify a frame(width: 100, height: 100), SwiftUI will make it 100x100 points. No matter which device. If you would like to adapt to the available space of a device, check the example I posted in this other question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56853211/7786555

Additionally, here's the documentation to get the screen size for your current device:

**The bounding rectangle of the screen, measured in points:**
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscreen/1617838-bounds

**The bounding rectangle of the physical screen, measured in pixels.**
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscreen/1617810-nativebounds

Comment: Thanks and sorry for late and my bad english. 
So, If I want to make rectangle with half-screen size (like width/2 and height/2), should I have to get size with GeometryReader and apply that size to my rectangle? I just asked to check if I understand correctly.

Comment: Technically you have 2 options. One, is using GeometryReader, which works just fine (you can learn how to here https://swiftui-lab.com/geometryreader-to-the-rescue/). The other option is using .relativeWidth(0.5).relativeHeight(0.5). Unfortunately, as of beta3, there is a bug. Fortunately though, there is a workaround too (https://stackoverflow.com/a/56885658/7786555)