# SwiftUI: Dynamically set size for Image

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want to show an image in a View, where the image source will vary in size.
Is there a way to dynamically adjust the size of the image to the width of the containing view or get the screen size even?
I have a horizontal scrollview with each element being a Stack of an image and a text. I would like to size every image depending on the screen width, since I want to be independent of the device. 
How would you do that in SwiftUI?
Thanks!

```
struct ImageRow: View {
    var items: [ImageWithDescription]

    var body: some View {

        ScrollView(showsHorizontalIndicator: false) {
                HStack(alignment: .bottom){

                    ForEach(self.items.identified(by: \.name)) { item in
                       Spacer()
                        VStack {
                        Image(uiImage: item.image ?? UIImage())
                            .resizable()
                            .frame(minWidth: (item.image.size.width) / 3, height: (item.image.size.height) / 3)
                            .cornerRadius(20, antialiased: true)
                            .clipShape(Rectangle())
                            .shadow(radius: 10)

                        Text(item.name)
                        .color(.primary)
                        .font(.subheadline)

                        }
                    }
                    .padding()
                }
                }
                .frame(height: 300)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the size of the screen (or window, in case you are using an iPad with split screen).

In the example below, the top view uses GeometryReader to get the size and passes it down the hierarchy. The subview uses that data to create a blue rectangle with half the size of the screen. It will also adapt if the device is rotated.

GeometryReader has many features, and although they are barely documented, I've written an article which fully explains how to use them: https://swiftui-lab.com/geometryreader-to-the-rescue/

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {

        GeometryReader { geometry in
            MySubview(size: geometry.size)
        }

    }
}

struct MySubview: View {
    let size: CGSize

    var body: some View {
        print("size = \(size)")
        return Color.blue.frame(width: size.width / 2, height: size.height / 2).fixedSize()
    }
}
```

Comment: When I did this, I got error " Cannot convert value of type 'CGSize.Type' to expected argument type 'CGSize'".  do you know how to fix this :?